# Which class is Maven calling?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am looking at an internal Maven application I am building in IntelliJ (same results in Eclipse), and everything looks perfectly clean.

I run clean and compile from IntelliJ (using IntelliJ build or using IntelliJ Maven support) and everything compiles fine.

However when I run the build from the command line (mvn clean compile) I am getting build exceptions (see below).

The command line seems to be looking for a genericized parameter (to the "with" method), which we are indeed passing in correctly. However it is complaining as if we were passing in a non-generic parameter.

Obviously mvn on the command line is using a different version of the "with" method than IntelliJ.

Is there any way to ask Maven to tell me which version of a class it is using, in terms of group, artifact and version of the containing jar?

Here is the precise error

```
[ERROR] \dev\try-deploy-1\src\main\java\com\victor\webui\WebUserInterface.java:[147,47] 
attribute(java.lang.String,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>) in 
org.openqa.selenium.lift.Matchers cannot be applied to 
(java.lang.String,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Object>)
```

Comment: This looks like a unit/integration tests which does not belong to `src/main/java`. It belongs to `src/test/java` instead.

Comment: Yes and no. It is a production application that routinely performs a series of smoke tests to monitor the health of our applications. We had to override the scope of selenium, JUnit, and Hamcrest to compile just for this application

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have another version of the class somewhere? try adding a comment on a new line in the file so the line number changes, and re-run the maven compile to see if it still gives the same line number for the error.

Comment: No I checked that exactly as you suggested. Great idea though, thanks. There is definitely another version of the class but I have a feeling it's in a conflicting jar

Comment: It could be that the maven build is using an older Java version than the IntelliJ build? Check the build configuration in the pom.

Comment: I will do that. Interesting observation; I am using JDK6u45. When I ran the same pom from the command line in Java 8, everything worked. I am leaning to the opinion that there is a bug in the javac compiler dealing with compiling the generics. When I removed the generics <..> from the declarations, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, sorry I know you are using IntelliJ, the maven build usually does an offline build that's why it's so fast.  There is a way to force it to do a clean with all the jars though and I use that when I get in a bind. It is the Update Project command and it has a box to force the update of snapshots and releases. Maybe Intellij has something like that?  Also I'd verify the version you are using on command line is the same as the one IntelliJ is using (I have a few versions installed). You can check Settings in IntelliJ and

`mvn -v`

on the command line.  Finally I'd make sure the settings.xml files you are using for command line and IntelliJ are the same file.

Good luck.

Comment: Good suggestion, but settings.xml is the same. I don't see anything like that update in IntelliJ. Seems like Maven should be able to take a class file and tell you where it came from

Comment: Is there a Package Explorer like view in IntelliJ? You can use that view to see what packages and classes are in your maven dependencies visually. Or is there a way to open an object by type? In Eclipse it's control+shift+t if the you can see what jar the class comes from in that view too.

Comment: Yes, the correct artifact is displayed. I refactored the code and removed the generics, and it is now compiling perfectly. I am pretty sure it is a bug in the javac compiler